# BOOT_COMPLETED isn't received by my physical phone Asus

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted, jobintentservice, asus

I tested a `BroadcastReceiver` which runs a `JobIntentService` in emulator, that worked successfully .

but it fails when i test the code to my physical phone ASUS ZE551ML .

Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

  <service android:name=".MyJobIntentService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"

        android:exported="false"/>
</application>
```

BroadcastReceiver class :

```
package com.packt.backgroundservicedemo;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Write Code..

        if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyJobIntentService.class);
            i.putExtra("sleepTime", 12);
            MyJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context,i);
//            context.startService(i);

        }


    }
}
```

JobIntentService class :

```
package com.packt.backgroundservicedemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {

    static final int JOB_ID = 15;


    static void enqueueWork(Context context,Intent intent){
        enqueueWork(context,MyJobIntentService.class,JOB_ID,intent);
    }

    private static final String TAG = MyJobIntentService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Task Execution Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {

        // Write code here..
        Log.i(TAG,"onHandleWork(), Thread name:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        int duration = intent.getIntExtra("sleepTime",-1);
        int ctr = 1;
        //Dummy long operation
        while (ctr<=duration){
            Log.i(TAG,"Time elapsed " + ctr + " secs");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ctr++;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Task Execution Finished",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    }
}
```

Repeat : the code works well at emulator devices, pre Oreo and Oreo devices.

The log doesn't contain any related `boot_completed reveiced` for my application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an Auto-start Manager application which was denying my app to run at startup.

[image: Asus Auto-start Manager]

Now my application works well at start.

Thanks @Arseny Levin for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is - your emulator doesn't have a passcode lock, while your real device does. `BOOT_COMPLETED` is broadcast only after unlocking with the passcode, and you'll have to wait for the other `BroadcastReceiver`s to receive this event (other apps that registered for this event), depending on where you're in the queue of the system.

Comment: Thanks Arseny, but the application doesn't receive `broadcast receiver` also after unlocking the device.

Also i checked the log and saw some apps receiving `boot_completed` receiver.

Comment: Is there any specific code or actions i can do to support ASUS mobiles ?
I feel the problem comes from it.

Comment: Don't know specifically about ASUS. Perhaps check if they have their own permission manager (like Xiaomi does), which requires using their specific API.